# How to set some text in dropdown after jquery dialogbox is loaded using jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my dropdownlist code

```
<select id="timezone">
<option value="US">(GMT - 06:00)Central Time(US & Canada)</option>
<option value="India">(UTC + 05:30)Chennai,kolkatta,Mumbai,New Delhi</option>                    
</select>
```

I want to change the text in the dropdown to (UTC + 05:30)Chennai,kolkatta,Mumbai,New Delhi not based on the value attribute. i need some other method

**Question modified:**
The setting value of dropdown code should be executed when my jquery dialogbox is opened .. where should i write the code for setting the value of dropdownlist

Please help me

Comment: do you want to change the selected value for the dropdown or the display text for the second option

Comment: i want to change the selected value based on the text

Comment: Try `$('#timezone').find('option:contains("New Delhi")').prop('selected',true)`

Comment: @SandeepChary see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var theText = " (UTC + 05:30)Chennai,kolkatta,Mumbai,New Delhi";
$("#timezone option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: I think this works but actually my problem is this should happen when my jquery dialogbox is opened .. any help please

Comment: at this line of code execution $("#timezone option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected'); the html content is not yet rendered

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#timezone').find('option:contains("Chennai,kolkatta,Mumbai,New Delhi")').prop('selected', true)
```

or try with one city name

```
$('#timezone').find('option:contains("New Delhi")').prop('selected', true)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8DmjV/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#timezone')
.find('option:contains("Chennai,kolkatta,Mumbai,New Delhi")')
.prop('selected', true);

//or

$('#timezone')
.find('option[value="India")')
.prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var city = "Chennai";
$('#timezone option:contains("'+ city +'")')[0].selected = true;
```

*[demo](http://jsbin.com/UfOvOJOG/1/edit)*

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the following code:

```
$("#timezone").find("option").eq(1).html("new text");
```

the `1` in `eq` is actually the index of the `option` tags. The start from `0`.

Comment: thanks for the reply .. i need the text to be changed not based on index or value ... i need to change by giving a new text

Comment: I don't understand. You need some thing to filter the options and choose the one which you want the text changed. Do you mean that you want to pass an option value and use that as a filter. Then when this text matches some of the options to change its value.